# CSV download for rest API not working

Tags: rest, csv, response, resteasy, content-disposition

I am trying to download a csv by writing the data to response output stream. I have set the content disposition as text/csv , application/octet-stream, openxml, ms-excel.Tried including accept header.
Also tried Response Builder to build bytearrayoutputstream.

Even created a file locally and tried to download.

But, I am getting the csv response in the response body. The download does not happen, there is no prompt to download. I am using RESTEASY JAXRS.

```
@POST
@Path("/response")
@Produces({"application/vnd.ms-excel"})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void viewSomething(PolicyRequest input,@Context HttpServletResponse responseExcel){

    try
    {
        List<List<String>> data= getData(something)
        String filename =   "sample.csv";

        responseExcel.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+filename);    
        responseExcel.addHeader("Content-Type" ,"application/vnd.ms-excel");


        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(responseExcel.getOutputStream());
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(osw);

        for(List<String> rows : data){
            String[] row = rows.toArray(new String[0]);
            writer.writeNext(row);
        }
writer.flush();
writer.close();
osw.close();                    
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the wrong Content-Type header: `@Produces({"application/vnd.ms-excel"})`

It should be `@Produces({"text/csv"})`

Also explicitly setting the header should be obsolete as the `@Produces` does that for you